# Difference in titration curves

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, titration

In my titration curve for HCl being titrated with NaOH, the initial pH-value was plotted as 2.1 according to a pH-meter. When I found the equivalence point and calculated the concentration of HCl, it was 0.075 M. I calculated how much the initial pH-value should be from that by -lg(0.075) which is around 1.12. That is way off from the original pH-value I got.

Why did this happen? Is it because the risk of me calibrating the pH-meter incorrectly? If that is the case, will the x-value of the equilibrium point also be wrong?? For the latter, I feel like the answer would be no, because what is wrong is that if the pH-meter was calibrated wrong, then all of the values would be 0.9 pH higher than what they should be, so the curve would only differ in the y-direction, but would be exactly the same in the x-direction. Is that correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your electrode is incorrectly calibrated. But it may be another effect : you should know that at high acidic concentration, the pH values **is not obtained by taking the logarithm** of the concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$. At high acidic concentration, the concentration should be replaced by the activity, which could be rather different from the concentration. Just for the fun try this experimentation : Take your $\ce{HCl}$ solution with an electrode showing  pH $2.1$. Add an equal volume of saturated $\ce{NaCl}$ solution (which is neither acidic nor basic). You will not believe your eyes by reading your electrode : The pH values goes down to $1$, as if diluting the initial solution produces an increase of concentration !

The activity is sometimes described as the amount of $\ce{H3O+}$ ions divided by the volume of the so-called "free water" (and not by the volume of the solution). In concentrated solutions the "free water" is this small amount of water that is free to move, and **not** attracted and fixed around the ions. One Liter $1 M$ $\ce{HCl}$, should contain much less that $1$ Liter free water, maybe about $0.1$ Liter free water, or less.

Comment: Intreresting! I did not know about that. Thank you!